# Swift naming conventions for booleans, constants and @IBAction selectors?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, naming-conventions, constants

I have been reading the [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) for `Swift` and some posts regarding naming those entities I said in the title of the question, but I am still not clear about that.

I am developing in `Swift 3`.

1. Boolean variables should be prefixed with `is-`, with `has-`, or both prefixes are appropriate?
2. Methods returning `Bool` selectors should also be prefixed `is`/`has`?
3. Constant variables that, for example, you define to avoid magic numbers, should start with a `k`? (for example, `kMaxLength`). I think this was a convention for `Objective-C`, is it for `Swift` as well?
4. The name for an `@IBAction` selector, should refer to the control that triggers the action, or the task it does? (For example: `doneButtonTapped` vs `validateInput`)

Comment: It's rather a matter of opinion, but if you want to follow the guidelines properly: 1+2 yes, 3 no, 4 task

Comment: Documents are always just talks. The best way to understand something is to see implementation. We can check Swift libraries and find the best practice. And for `@IBAction` I personally feel the way you have mentioned is right and it is also backed by guidelines.

Comment: Regarding number 4: I would consider implementing both methods: `doneButtonTapped` receives the event and delegates to the method `validateInput`.

Answer (score 7):

Swift general naming conventions are available here https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#general-conventions

> - **Uses of Boolean methods and properties should read as assertions about
>     the receiver** when the use is nonmutating, e.g. `x.isEmpty`,
>     `line1.intersects(line2)`.
> - The names of other **types, properties, variables, and constants should read as nouns.**

Comment: What about a type representing a to-do item, for example? It may have a flag indicating whether the task has been "done" yet. The property is supposed to be writable. In this case, I have two choices: write `item.isDone = true` where the use is **not** "nonmutating", or write `item.done = true` in which case the getter would be `let isDone = item.done`. What do you think?

Comment: Assuming that I decide to name the property "done". One way to make it possible to query the property using the "is" prefix is to extend the type: `var isDone: Bool { return done }`. The obvious downside of this is that there are two different ways to read the same property.